# How and when can I ask my boss (again) if he will hire me back as an intern?

Tags: recruitment, job-change

I'm a 19 year old IT student, currently doing an apprenticeship where I do 3 days a week at my employer and 2 days a week in school. My course is 2 years, 1 year and 2 years to end with a diploma after five years.

I'm ending the first 2 years phase and I want to ask my boss if he will hire me again for another year, but I'm pretty uncomfortable about this.

My company has only 5 employees, that's a start-up. My boss, a secretary, one developer that was on an internship at the beginning (2 years ago), another new student doing an apprenticeship and me.

I'm doing a good job: I'm now autonomously working. This week, the principal developer is in vacation, so I'm deploying in production and fixing a production bug. I think this is a pretty high level of responsibility for a student with only 1 year of experience.

So how should I ask? I did ask 5 months ago, but my boss told me that as a start-up he couldn't be sure about this.

I'm also wondering *when* to do this - should I do it with other employees near?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere it's my boss, not my friend..

Comment: @JoeStrazzere in last edit I specify that I've already asked before. Asking again make me feel like a spam in inbox..

Comment: You asked 5 months ago. It worked, he just could not give you an answer at that time. Ask again in the same way. It seems he was not offended.

Comment: I will edit plus yeah you're right, he is cool..

Comment: @JoeStrazzere that's right, but now it's about "When". With other employees near ? When we are alone ?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere it look cool when I read it. I will do my best, thanks

Comment: I've copyedited the question a bit. If you think I've changed the meaning of anything you wrote, apologies and please do edit it again to more accurately reflect your question. Just one style note: we don't use "edit" markers in Stack Exchange posts: just make the current version of the question reflect what you want to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So how should I ask ?
>
> EDIT : I already asked 5 months ago, he told me that as a Start-up he
>   couldn't be sure about this.

Five months is a lot of time to pass.  Your boss may have gotten busy and simply forgot.  I don't see the harm at all in simply asking again.

I would suggest if at all possible you ask him face to face.  If this is not possible, bring it up in a phone conversation, and if all else fails send them another email.

As you progress in your career, you have to overcome the fear of asking for what you want.

Comment: Right, he always forgot because he's so busy.. I'm over thinking easily sorry.
Another question, when should I ask ? When we are alone ? Employees in same workspace aren't a problem ?

Comment: I would try to catch him in a one on one situation if at all possible.

Comment: Right, let's give me a try

Comment: he hire me again :)